# In (Django) web application should if-else logic be at a high level (view) or a low level (template)?

Tags: web-development, django

Given a (Django) web application following the model-template-view model, when returning a template based on an object should if-else logic be in the view or the template?

The API endpoint (view) gets a request to display a template based on an object (model). Some parts of the template are conditional on properties of the object, while other elements in the template are "common": they don't depend on the properties.

Is it better to have two templates and have if-else logic in the view that chooses between the templates or to have one template that includes the if-else logic.

If there is no clear-cut answer, what are the considerations?

- Is it simply that if the differences between two templates are large enough, then this might warrant having two templates (if-else in the view), instead of having the if-else logic in the template?
- What about if-else statements in Django templates being messy and harder to read?

Comment: I keep coming back to this question, but I can't see a way to answer it. Mainly, I don't think of an API endpoint as a "view". I frequently use "template" and "view" interchangebly. Typically a "view" is what the end user interacts with, which could be generated from a template and a model. I think the way you have defined "view" is making it hard to answer your question.

Comment: Thanks! Hm... I guess in MVC what I call "view" would be the Controller? But yeah my question is not very good somehow.